# create separate column by getting Numbers from the another string column in kdb+q

Tags: kdb

Hi I'm new to kdb and I wanted help with below question
Suppose I have a table

```
t:([] price:100 200; Text:("Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250";"Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"))
```

from the text "Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold is 250"
I want to have two new columns with selling price and purchase price.

[image: result table should look like]

I have been trying to work on strings first and I could get the index but having trouble with getting numbers correctly. not sure if that would be an efficient solution either.

```
b:"Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250"

q)" " vs string (first ss[b;"Selling price "])+count "Selling price "

q)"14"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generalize this a bit by creating a function that takes a string and a list of string patterns and returns the first word following the occurrence of any of the patterns in the string

```
q) findFirstWordAfterPatterns: { [txt; patterns] : { first " " vs (1 + count[string y `pattern] + y `indexes) _ x }[txt;] each ungroup flip `pattern`indexes! flip  (`$patterns) ,' enlist each ss[txt;] each patterns; };
q) findFirstWordAfterPatterns["foo bar hello world foo bar"; ("foo"; "hello")]
"bar"
"bar"
"world"
```

you can then run an update command on your table to add two new columns that are populated by calling this function against the Text column:

```
q)buyPatterns:  ("purchase price"; "buy price");
q)sellPatterns: enlist "Selling price"
q) t:([] price:100 200 300; Text:("Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250";"Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"; "blah blah blah purchase price 100 blah blah blah buy price 200 blah blah blah purchase price 300 blah blah blah"))
q)update SellingPrices:findFirstWordAfterPatterns[; sellPatterns]'[Text],    PurchasePrices:findFirstWordAfterPatterns[; buyPatterns]'[Text] from t
price Text                                                                                                              SellingPrices PurchasePrices
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100   "Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250"                                                          ,"100"        ,"200"
200   "Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"                                                                        ,"200"        ,"300"
300   "blah blah blah purchase price 100 blah blah blah buy price 200 blah blah blah purchase price 300 blah blah blah" ()            ("100";"300";"200")
```

if you only want the first such occurrence, and you wants them converted from string to number, you can tweak the update statement using first each and "F"$ to convert to float (you could instead use "I"$ to convert to integer):

```
q)update SellingPrices:first each "F"$findFirstWordAfterPatterns[; sellPatterns]'[Text], PurchasePrices:first each "F"$findFirstWordAfterPatterns[; buyPatterns]'[Text] from t
price Text                                                                                                              SellingPrices PurchasePrices
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100   "Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250"                                                          100           200
200   "Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"                                                                        200           300
300   "blah blah blah purchase price 100 blah blah blah buy price 200 blah blah blah purchase price 300 blah blah blah"               100
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really helpful I've got to learn a lot :)

Comment: To handle capital letters you can supply all patterns in lower case `sellPatterns:lower enlist "Selling price"` and then use `lower Text` in the queries so both `Selling price` and `selling price` will match.

Comment: That's such a great point ! Thanks @rianoc :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `Text` column will always have the same structure:

```
q)t,'flip`SellingPrice`PurchasePrice!("  J   J";" ")0:t`Text
price Text                                                     SellingPrice PurchasePrice
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100   "Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250" 100          200
200   "Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"               200          300
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic version assuming the order is the same in each piece of text:

```
t,'exec {`SellingPrice`PurchasePrice!2#{x where not null x}"J"$" " vs @[x;where not x in .Q.n;:;" "]} each Text from t
price Text                                                     SellingPrice PurchasePrice
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100   "Selling price 100 and purchase price 200 threshold 250" 100          200
200   "Selling price 200 and purchase price 300"               200          300
```